# Hibernate retrieving object with special primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

This is how I can retrieve an Object with the primary key 1.

```
user = null;

session = sessionFactory.openSession();

session.beginTransaction();

user = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);

System.out.println(user);
```

But I want to know, how I can retrieve an Object, that has a primary key like: "Primary:1_Key_1-ID"?

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key is type of `String` then this works for you.

```
String key= "1_Key_1-ID";
UserDetails user = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, key);
```